# How to get all leaf nodes from any parent node in a tree

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, tree

I am developing an app in android using Sqlite, I have a tree structure which I represent in the db like so :

```
        +------+------+-------+------+
        |comp_id nodeId parent| text |
        |------|------|-------|------|
        |  146 |  1   |  -1   | Top  |
        |      |      |       |      |
        | 146  |  2   |  1    | Ch1  |
        |      |      |       |      |
        | 146  |  3   |  2    | Leaf |
        |      |      |       |      |
        |  ... |      |       |      |
        | 152  |  1   |  -1   | Top  |
        +------+------+-------+------+
```

I am having difficulty coding an algorithm in a self contained method like below to return me all the leafs under any node.

```
Node
{
   public Node[] getAllLeafs()
   {
      // traverse all the way down the tree
      // and get only leafs
   }
}
```

If there is a way to accomplish this more easily by modifying my table structure and/or using SQL please mention that as I am able to do so.

Comment: You have two nodes with the same `nodeId`. What is the meaning of `comp_id`? Show an example of the desired output!

Comment: @CL. `comp_id` means compilation id, its like a book and the nodes are chapter names (which may have sub-chapters), and the leafs are like pages or paragraphs. That's the closest example I can give.

Answer (score 0):

Select all rows whose `node_id`s are not parents of some other rows, i.e. they are leaves.

```
select *
from   tree_table
where  node_id not in (
   select distinct parent from tree_table
);
```

Comment: Thanks Boris please see my edit, more than one comp_id is possible.

Comment: That is not what has been asked! I guess he only those nodes which are leaves in the subtree with the given node as root.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a recursive method, that would return an array of all the leafs from its children, if a node has children, or the `Node` itself, if it doesn't have children, therefore is a leaf itself.

```
public Node[] getAllLeafs() {

    ArrayList<Node> allLeafs = new ArrayList<Node>();

    if (getAllChildren().size() == 0) {
        allLeafs.add(this);
        return (Node[]) allLeafs.toArray();
    } else {
        for (Node child : this.getAllChildren()) {
            allLeafs.addAll(child.getAllLeafs());
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can keep the logic within one method and don't have to redundantly traverse unimportant nodes. The implementation of the structural methods is up to you.

Comment: please can you show the two methods `getAllLeafs` and `getAllChildren` in pseudo-code.

Comment: well getAllLeafs is written in the code, a field of children is an attribute of Node, therefore you can get it directly, there's no algorithm involved

Comment: It seems your `getLeafs()` does not take parameters yet you are calling it with a parameter?! `getAllLeafs(child)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic would work:

```
select node_id
from tree_table where node_id not in 
(select a.node_id 
from tree_table as a, tree_table as b
where a.node_id = b.parent);
```

The inner query finds out those nodes which are also parents in the same table. The outer query finds out the nodes which are not parents of any node and hence must be leaf nodes. Hope this helps!

Comment: You were right about the answer from Boris, but you have done the same mistake! Please treat the input `node_id` as root, and include the `comp_id` in your solution.

Comment: Oh! I thought you said Boris was right.
In this case, I will need some more thinking. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is the reason to fetch all nodes under instead of all **direct** nodes? Second option is obviously simple.

I don't think that there is a reasonable solution, maybe graph databases. The point is that you can either:

1. To have all parent ids (direct and non-direct) persisted along with every node. You could design new table having foreign keys for that. But this solution seems like heavyweight. Speaking of which such table should grow exponentially.
2. To fetch the whole tree **together**. This is the approach we are using within our app after four years of database research. DB is designed to fetch data lying next to each other because of buffering and reading of hard-drive blogs ahead. You can improve this solution using correct indexes and so on. What I'm saying is that sometimes it's better approach to fetch continuous drive segment from DB than making complex queries and than make searching for all nodes in java code.

   Note that one fetch of the whole tree (by root index id) can do DB within one DB read. On the other hand, usually a select using **nested query** or using **joins** uses more reads, requires ids matching, maybe temporary table and so on. (index handling, locking, etc.)

   You should definitely use various NoSQL DBs but also RDBMS.

Comment: Unfortunately with my tree containing perhaps near a million rows I cannot load it all into memory on a mobile device, and I am not aware of any other db than Sqlite available to me.

Comment: So I would use another table containing all parent for all nodes and you can query such table very easily.

Comment: Please give an example using my data, feel free to split into multiple tables but remember the tables will contain many 100,000 rows and space is precious.

Answer (score 0):

With SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use a query like the following to compute the subtree beginning at a specific node, and then get the leaves in that subtree:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE subtree(comp_id, nodeId, parent, text)
AS (SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE comp_id = 146 AND nodeId = 1  -- start node
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MyTable.*
    FROM MyTable
    JOIN subtree ON MyTable.comp_id = subtree.comp_id
                AND MyTable.parent  = subtree.nodeid)
SELECT *
FROM subtree
WHERE nodeid NOT IN (SELECT parent
                     FROM subtree)
```

With earlier SQLite versions, you would have to retrieve the nodes at each level by hand.

Comment: Its impossible for me to get v3.8.3 on android. The latest supported is 3.7.11. Sorry I didn't have enough tags to add `android`, didn't think I would need to mention it either.